# How do i convert JSON?

Tags: reactjs

I am bit of an api noob.
So, I am using an api and have received the correct response!

I have a question is there a better approach this issue, also the function changeProductTitle() is throwing me an error , which I have no idea of fixing .

Heres the specific code:

```
handleSubmit() {
  axios.get('shopify/api/products/587186143290.json')
  .then(function (response){
    let res = response["data"];
    res = res["product"];
    res = res["title"];
    changeProductTitle(res) {
      this.setState({
        productTitle: res
      })
    }
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(function (error){
    console.log(error);
  })

}
```

Comment: changeProductWithTitle() function ? ah ok you probably meant changeProductTitle()

Comment: You can use Javascript's `JSON.parse(res)` to get a Javascript object to work with. Then your code might look like `const title = JSON.parse(res).product.title;`

Comment: And what about the changeProductTitle

Comment: btw you are missing function head declaration there

Comment: replace changeProductTitle(res) with function changeProductTitle() { ... } or I'm not sure what you tried to do there because I don't see the entire code. Did you perhaps tried to call that function with res object ? like so: changeProductTitle(res); ??

Comment: Yes i did try defining the changeProductTitle() outside and tried calling it from here, but it gave me an error!